# I get no water from the kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens, faucet

I've read the answers on this site, and now I'm wondering, where is the aerator?

OP: noted there was no water from the Faucet or Dishwasher, in subsequent follow up, it was noted the dishwasher does work & use of the Hot or Cold produces no water flow.

Comment: Is this a new install? Tell us a little about the install. If you replaced only the faucet itself, could be a cartridge issue. If new piping was installed, could be a combination of aerator/cartridge clogs from pipe debris. Could be a bad supply valve. Could be there's another valve going to your kitchen sink somewhere under the house.

Comment: can you share a picture of the where the water supply to the dishwasher is coming from? Are you on well water? has your toilet water been discolored at all near the time or recently before the sink and dishwasher stopped working?

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question the aerator of a typical kitchen faucet is located as shown below by the arrow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you and I feel a little embarrassed for not knowing this. And I'm looking for anything that could block water flow, right?

Comment: Is it just hot water or cold water problem? See other answer for suggestions around the shut off valve under sink. However if it was a shut off valve I would expect it to be affecting just hot or cold.

Comment: No water, hot or cold is coming from the kitchen faucet. The dishwasher is getting water, but not the sink. Not a drip or noise or anything.

Comment: If it is a common problem for hot and cold and the dishwasher is not a problem (you may want to edit your question in this regard) then it is likely in the faucet and not in the shutoff valves under the sink. A plugged aerator could be the problem - especially if you noticed a phase of reduced flow before the water stopped all together.

Comment: I'm glad the answers on this site helped you to determine it could be a plugged aerator. That is 100% a possibility. Most of them can be unscrewed and it is therefore a pretty quick check to just take it off and see if you can get water flow. If not, we will all want to know if you have one or two handles for hot/cold water.

Comment: Thank you, yes the answers did help. It was just what you said it might be, build up in the lines. Who knew? Thank you for corresponding with me. You've been wonderful. I'm not a plumber or rooter and I could of guess what it might be all day long. Didn't have to, again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The aerator is mounted on the end of the faucet and is probably not the problem. I am assuming you are speaking of the cold water supply. If you do not get water from these 2 items then the problem is in the supply piping. Chemicals in the water can coat and plug smaller passage ways in the valves and tubing connections. My neighbor had very little cold water flow and the problem was a plugged shut-off valve under the kitchen sink. The valve was replaced and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two knobs usually located under the sink. One is for Hot water and the other for cold water - it is where you can directly turn off water on the Sink or Dishwasher with out affecting the rest of the house.

**EDIT 9-2-2017** see the Additional Causes listed below the picture.

They look like this:

[image: Water Shut off valve]

**EDIT 9-2-2017**

If you now have water to your Dishwasher and no water from the faucet.

1: Single Handle Faucet ? Then the Faucet unit could be bad - there is usually a cartridge fitting that you can replace.

2: You do not state if it is a new install or older install - it could be the handle is not properly attached to the cartridge .. on a single handle there is usually a screw that fits into the handle mechanics - it may have backed out or is broken.

You could have pinched the lines to your faucet if it was a new install and using PVC line - UNLIKELY but doable.

I would not suspect a clogged aerator even though it is possible - you would notice a trickle effect and if this is the case - buy a new faucet and install a filter on the lines - too much sediment and garbage in your water line.

Comment: This is most likely not the issue with the subsequent follow up from OP in comments that states the dishwasher water does work